# Rotating a Row of Textures

Tags: opengl, c++, sdl2, linux, glew

**Preface**: In Linux, using C++11, SDL2, GLEW, and OpenGL.

Hello Ladies/Gents,

I am reaching out as I'm stuck on a fairly simple problem that a decade out of school has further hindered. Specifically, I am able to draw a single texture, rotate, grow, extend as I see fit without any real issue. The issue comes when I choose to repeat the texture (at original size or modified size). I am having the hardest time rotating the boxes as well. My debug box rotates without issue, but it is a set of indices.

Could any of you magnificent people offer any pointers or suggestions on how to go about this? I've included the related code bits below.

This is *drawRepeat*, which handles taking a single texture and it's size (destRect.z = width, destRect.w = height), then repeating through the sizeBounds

```
void SpriteBatch::drawRepeat(const glm::vec4& destRect, const glm::vec4& uvRect, const glm::vec4& sizeBounds, GLuint texture, float depth, const ColorRGBA8& color, float angle) // angle in radians
{
    // fail without info provided
    if(!m_screenHeight || !m_screenWidth || !m_scale) { GameEngine101::fatalError("No screen width/height or scale specified for drawRepeat!"); }

    int x_iterations = static_cast<int>(sizeBounds.z / destRect.z);
    int y_iterations = static_cast<int>(sizeBounds.w / destRect.w);

    // tmp variables
    glm::vec4 tmpDestRect = glm::vec4(0.0f);

    // create glyphs
    for(uint ix = 0; ix < x_iterations; ix++)
    {
        tmpDestRect = destRect;
        tmpDestRect.x = destRect.x + ( destRect.z * ix ); // something else needs to happen here?

        for(uint iy = 0; iy < y_iterations; iy++)
        {
            tmpDestRect.y = destRect.y + ( destRect.w * iy ); // something else needs to happen here?
            if(angle != 0.0f) { m_glyphs.emplace_back(tmpDestRect, uvRect, texture, depth, color, angle); }
            else { m_glyphs.emplace_back(tmpDestRect, uvRect, texture, depth, color); }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the constructor for **Glyph** for rotating textures. Below it is the  struct for **Vertex** and the function for *rotatePoint*.

```
Glyph::Glyph(const glm::vec4& destRect,const glm::vec4& uvRect, GLuint Texture, float Depth, const ColorRGBA8& color, float angle) : texture(Texture), depth(Depth)
{
    glm::vec2 halfDimensions(destRect.z / 2.0f, destRect.w / 2.0f);

    // get points centered at origin
    glm::vec2 tl(-halfDimensions[0], halfDimensions[1]); // top left
    glm::vec2 bl(-halfDimensions[0], -halfDimensions[1]); // bottom left
    glm::vec2 tr(halfDimensions[0], halfDimensions[1]); // top right
    glm::vec2 br(halfDimensions[0], -halfDimensions[1]); // bottom right

    // rotate the points
    tl = rotatePoint(tl, angle) + halfDimensions;
    bl = rotatePoint(bl, angle) + halfDimensions;
    tr = rotatePoint(tr, angle) + halfDimensions;
    br = rotatePoint(br, angle) + halfDimensions;

    // top left
    topLeft.setPosition(destRect.x + tl.x, destRect.y + tl.y);
    topLeft.setUV(uvRect.x, uvRect.y + uvRect.w);
    topLeft.color = color;
    // bottom left
    bottomLeft.setPosition(destRect.x + bl.x, destRect.y + bl.y);
    bottomLeft.setUV(uvRect.x, uvRect.y);
    bottomLeft.color = color;
    // top right
    topRight.setPosition(destRect.x + tr.x, destRect.y + tr.y);
    topRight.setUV(uvRect.x + uvRect.z, uvRect.y + uvRect.w);
    topRight.color = color;
    // bottom right
    bottomRight.setPosition(destRect.x + br.x, destRect.y + br.y);
    bottomRight.setUV(uvRect.x + uvRect.z, uvRect.y);
    bottomRight.color = color;
}


struct Vertex
{
    Vertex() {}
    ColorRGBA8 color = COLOR_WHITE; // 4 bytes for R G B A
    glm::vec2 pos = glm::vec2(0.0f);
    glm::vec2 uv = glm::vec2(0.0f); // UV texture coordinates

    void setPosition(float x, float y)
    {
        pos.x = x;
        pos.y = y;
    }

    void setColor(GLubyte R, GLubyte G, GLubyte B, GLubyte A)
    {
        color.r = R;
        color.g = G;
        color.b = B;
        color.a = A;
    }

    void setUV(float u, float v)
    {
        uv[0] = u;
        uv[1] = v;
    }

static glm::vec2 rotatePoint(glm::vec2 pos, float angle)
{
    glm::vec2 newVec;
    newVec.x = pos.x * cos(angle) - pos.y * sin(angle);
    newVec.y = pos.x * sin(angle) + pos.y * cos(angle);
    return newVec;
}
```

Below is an example of a single texture (white box is my debug box):
[image: Single texture, no rotation]

Next a single texture with rotation:
[image: Single texture, rotation]

I have made a comment in the first code block for drawRepeat where I believe the change needs to occur. Next post will contain the repeated textures and rotation. Lack of "reputation" prevents me from posting....

---

EDIT:

**Glyph** constructor without rotation:

```
Glyph::Glyph(const glm::vec4& destRect, const glm::vec4& uvRect, GLuint Texture, float Depth, const ColorRGBA8& color) : texture(Texture), depth(Depth)
{
    // top left
    topLeft.setPosition(destRect.x, destRect.y + destRect.w);
    topLeft.setUV(uvRect.x, uvRect.y + uvRect.w);
    topLeft.color = color;
    // bottom left
    bottomLeft.setPosition(destRect.x, destRect.y);
    bottomLeft.setUV(uvRect.x, uvRect.y);
    bottomLeft.color = color;
    // top right
    topRight.setPosition(destRect.x + destRect.z, destRect.y + destRect.w);
    topRight.setUV(uvRect.x + uvRect.z, uvRect.y + uvRect.w);
    topRight.color = color;
    // bottom right
    bottomRight.setPosition(destRect.x + destRect.z, destRect.y);
    bottomRight.setUV(uvRect.x + uvRect.z, uvRect.y);
    bottomRight.color = color;
}
```

More-recent *drawRepeat*:

```
void SpriteBatch::drawRepeat(const glm::vec4& destRect, const glm::vec4& uvRect, const glm::vec4& sizeBounds, GLuint texture, float depth, const ColorRGBA8& color, float angle) // angle in radians
{
    // fail without info provided
    if(!m_screenHeight || !m_screenWidth || !m_scale) { GameEngine101::fatalError("No screen width/height or scale specified for drawRepeat!"); }

    int x_iterations = static_cast<int>(sizeBounds.z / destRect.z);
    int y_iterations = static_cast<int>(sizeBounds.w / destRect.w);

    // tmp variable
    glm::vec4 tmpDestRect = destRect;

    // rotate by angle, converted from radians to degrees, on the z-axis
    glm::mat4 groupRotation;
    groupRotation = glm::rotate(groupRotation, glm::degrees(angle), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));

    GLint pUniformM = m_glsl->getUniformLocation("model");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(pUniformM, 1, GL_FALSE, &groupRotation[0][0]);

    // create glyphs
    for(uint ix = 0; ix < x_iterations; ix++)
    {
        tmpDestRect.x = destRect.x + ( destRect.z * ix ); // set X position

        for(uint iy = 0; iy < y_iterations; iy++)
        {
            tmpDestRect.y = destRect.y + ( destRect.w * iy ); // set Y position

            // rotate on angle, if exists
            //if(angle != 0.0f) { m_glyphs.emplace_back(tmpDestRect, uvRect, texture, depth, color, angle); }
            //else { m_glyphs.emplace_back(tmpDestRect, uvRect, texture, depth, color); }
            m_glyphs.emplace_back(tmpDestRect, uvRect, texture, depth, color);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Repeated texture, no rotation: http://i.imgur.com/udH3ApH.png
Repeated texture with rotation: http://i.imgur.com/TlJ5GFp.png

Sorry :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rotate the images as a unit instead of separately. This means, you need to apply the rotation after local transformation. Like this:

```
vPosition = singleImageRotation * cornerPosition; // Probably unnecessary step
vPosition = singleImagePosition + vPosition;
vPosition = groupRotation * vPosition;
vPosition = groupPosition + vPosition;
```

In this example the `singleImageRotation` and `groupRotation` are matrices that rotates your vertices. Also `singleImagePosition` is the image position in relation to the group's pivot point.

Comment: Relatively new to OpenGL still (sadly), please excuse the somewhat "obvious" questions: is 'vPosition' indicating the vertex position?

If so, would this mean that I should be applying the local transformations and rotations per vertex, to all those involved in the "group"?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Glorious. Will continue my hunt and I greatly appreciate your time and insight! :)

Comment: Lasse, if it's not too much trouble, could I pester you further to elaborate on how one might go about working out the singleImageRotation and groupRotation?

Comment: @BeauB. Sure thing. You are welcome to join the chat to ask questions from the community as I am not always available. I can answer your questions when I have the time to do so. Meanwhile you could read [this](https://open.gl/transformations) and [this](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/) tutorial for more information about transformations in OpenGL.

Comment: thank you again. The original reply (and one of the links) did help me make headway. At this point, I have a group rotating somewhat. I have made changes to the drawRepeat and resorted to using the non-rotating Glyph constructor, but, as you can see [here](http://i.imgur.com/m6LsB3O.gifv), it's a little silly.

Comment: I cannot start a chat due to lack of reputation. I'm fairly certain my issue currently is my lack of understanding in calculating the singleImageRotation (and/or singleImagePosition). The order of multiplication in the shader is correct ( `TranslationMatrix * RotationMatrix * ScaleMatrix * OriginalVector;` ), but it is still rotating strangely (as linked in previous comment).